# issues in changing table background-color

Tags: css

when i use background-color in my css to change the table background color instead of changing the colour of background it is changing the color of the text

here is my css code to style a table

```
.table_styling1 {
 table-layout:fixed;
 width:100%;  
 height:25px; 
 border:1px solid #ccc; 
 background-color:#8B7D7B;
 border-radius:4px;}

.table_styling1 th {
 padding:4px 6px 6px; 
 background:#444; 
 color:#fff; 
 text-align:center; 
 color:#ccc;}

.table_styling1 td {
 padding:2px 4px 4px; 
 background:#fff; 
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}

 .table_styling1 tr { 
 background-color:#FF83FA;}     

 .table_styling1 tr:hover {
 color:#4876FF;}
```

what should i change in my code so that i can apply a background-color to my table i even tried using background..it also did not worked

Comment: You are the first to have `background-color` changing the foreground color (i.e. the text color). If this is real, it is a bug…

Comment: @feeela So what should i do to change my background color, i tried by all possible means but could not get a solution. :(

Comment: I can't see your problem. Set up a test case fro all the other users here and ask a clear question, naming which of your style definitions "does not work" in point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.table_styling1 {       
   width:50%;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;}

.table_styling1 th{
   padding:4px;
   background:#444;
   color:#fff;}

.table_styling1 td {
   padding:2px 4px 4px;   
   border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}

.table_styling1 tr:hover {
   background:#4876FF;
   color:#1E1E1E;}                         

.table_styling1 table,th,td {
   border: 1px solid black;}
```

I read all css properties and found the answer, sorry for asking a wrong question